# R: Producing Plots of Multiple Dataframes Stored in a Vector

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I am attempting to produce plots for multiple data frames programmatically and give them each a unique name based on the name of the dataframe.  The data frames have been imported into R and given the names in namelist.  Each data frame has two columns. My goal is to generate ranks for the values in the second column and plot the values against the ranks.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

# List of data frame names 
namelist<- c("ara5", "brach5", "homo5", "hord5", "ory5", "sor5", "trit5", 
"zea5")

## Define function 
makePlot<- function(DF){
  sortindex<- order(DF[,2])
  rnk<-rank(DF[,2])
  temp<-as.tibble(cbind(rnk, DF[,2]))
  colnames(temp)<-c("rank", "count")
  p<- qplot(temp$rank, temp$count, xlab="rank", ylab="count", main=DF)
  file<-paste(DF, ".png", sep="")
  ggsave(file, plot=p, device="png")
}

## call function 
sapply(namelist, makePlot)
```

When I run the above code I receive the following error:
    Error in DF[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

I have confirmed that the dataframe that I am trying to pull data from has the correct number of dimensions, so I think that there is an issue with how this code is iterating through the list of dataframes.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you take the quotes off the names?  The name of a data frame object isn't generally in quotes.

Comment: Removing the quotes or trying list(ara5, ...etc) both produce errors.

Comment: What was the error?  There may be something else wrong.

Comment: Not sure.  I just worked around the problem by using a wrapper script in bash that passed the filename and the filename with the extension stripped off to the R script.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to use `get` to get the variable named with the string passed to the function.

i.e.:

```
makePlot<- function(DF){
  DF <- get(DF)
  ...
```

Comment: Didn't work.   Error in grDevices::dev.off() : 
  QuartzBitmap_Output - unable to open file 'c(624, 15, 599, 305, 597,